# GDB sets breakpoint on incorrect address

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, arm, breakpoints

I am debugging early Linux kernel assembly, and GDB does not seem to be setting breakpoints on the correct addresses.  objdump shows the address of the function:

```
c0008778 <__lookup_processor_type>:
```

And GDB seems to know the symbol address correctly, but it uses the wrong address when setting the breakpoint:

```
(gdb) print __lookup_processor_type
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x8778 <__lookup_processor_type>
(gdb) break __lookup_processor_type
Breakpoint 2 at 0x877c: file arch/arm/kernel/head-common.S, line 154.
```

There is an assembly instruction at the correct address:

```
c0008778:   e28f3030    add r3, pc, #48 ; 0x30
```

And manually setting the breakpoint works fine:

```
(gdb) break *0x8778
Breakpoint 3 at 0x8778: file arch/arm/kernel/head-common.S, line 153.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, __lookup_processor_type () at arch/arm/kernel/head-common.S:153
153     adr r3, __lookup_processor_type_data
```

Why does GDB refuse to set a breakpoint at the correct address?

In case it is relevant, here is how I am loading the symbol table.  Objdump reports the sections:

```
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .head.text    00000220  c0008000  c0008000  00008000  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .text         00470acc  c0008240  c0008240  00008240  2**6
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
```

And I load the symbols in GDB:

```
add-symbol-file vmlinux 0x8240 -s .head.text 0x8000
```

Comment: Apparently, `gdb` disagrees with you about which address is "correct".  The object code for the function may include a few instructions at the function entry point for setting up the stack and / or similar purposes, with `gdb` then setting the breakpoint at the first address that directly correlates to a statement in your source code.

Comment: Perhaps I should not have used the word "function".  There is no C code; this is just assembly.  __lookup_processor_type is a label.

Comment: If you do `set arm on`, gdb will provide some debugging output that includes where it stops in its scan of a function prologue. This won't fix your issue (but you've already found a workaround, and `b *__lookup_processor_type ` will also prevent gdb from skipping over a prologue) but may explain why gdb does what it does.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - I had not thought of *__lookup_processor_type.  That does work for me.  I was also having trouble with nexti not stepping over instructions, and thought there was some overall problem.  It looks like GDB is working right, and I'm misunderstanding.  Thanks!